# Wordpress can't see login page after migraton

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I already have a existing website on live server. I want to setup on local machine.

Following Steps has been taken

1) Download whole webiste.

2) Place whole code under htdocs/mywp.

3) Change the database file. replace all link from `https://www.example.com` to `http://10.1.15.5/mywp` ( this is my local ip).

4) Import the database and change the wp-config file.

5) Deleted .htaccess file

Now when i run

```
http://10.1.15.5/mywp
```

this is openign the page, but No CSS

and when i try to run 
 `http://10.1.15.5/mywp/wp-admin`  it doesn't  open 
it redirects to

```
 https://10.1.5.15/mywp/yourwp/login/?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2F10.1.5.15%2Fmywp%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1
```

I am new to wordpress.  There are few changes which i need to do.

Can anybody tell me what stpes can be taken

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if .htaccess will be auto-generated if you delete it. If it's not grab this one https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess and replace "RewriteBase" with "/mywp/". I am assuming htdocs is the root folder of your server.

Check from database's options table that siteurl and home options are set to http://10.1.15.5/mywp. Which should be if you search and replaced everything.

There also exists plugins like [duplicator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/) (haven't actually tested this myself) which can be used to take copies of your site and it handles migration to another server for you.

Hope this helps!